# Ansible AWS EC2 security group not updated

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

I have a play-book that created VPC security groups.
It works well, but many times, and update to an existing security group (mostly adding or removing ports) is not applied (not detected by Ansible).

**Original code:**

```
- name: create sg_riemann_elb rules
  local_action:
    module: ec2_group
    region: "{{ region }}"
    vpc_id: "{{ vpc.vpc.id }}"
    name: "sg_riemann_elb"
    description: security group for Riemann elb
    rules:
      - proto: tcp
        from_port: 5555
        to_port: 5556
        group_name: "{{ realm }}_sg_base_server"
        group_desc: security group for all servers
    rules_egress:
      - proto: tcp
        from_port: 5555
        to_port: 5556
        group_name: "{{ realm }}_sg_riemann_server"
        group_desc: security group for Riemann servers
```

**New code:** (added port **4567**)

```
- name: create sg_riemann_elb rules
  local_action:
    module: ec2_group
    region: "{{ region }}"
    vpc_id: "{{ vpc.vpc.id }}"
    name: "sg_riemann_elb"
    description: security group for Riemann elb
    rules:
      - proto: tcp
        from_port: 4567
        to_port: 4567
        group_name: "{{ realm }}_sg_base_server"
        group_desc: security group for all servers
    rules:
      - proto: tcp
        from_port: 5555
        to_port: 5556
        group_name: "{{ realm }}_sg_base_server"
        group_desc: security group for all servers
    rules_egress:
      - proto: tcp
        from_port: 5555
        to_port: 5556
        group_name: "{{ realm }}_sg_riemann_server"
        group_desc: security group for Riemann servers
```

**The output from the Ansible run is:**

```
TASK [vpc : create sg_riemann_server rules] ************************************
ok: [localhost -> localhost] => {"changed": false, "group_id": "sg-ce89bcaa"}
```

Any idea why it's not updated with new port (4567)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two items with a key `rules` in the task `create sg_riemann_elb rules` and one is overwriting the other. The fix is to define only one `rules` key with a list of security group rules, like this:

```
    ...
    description: security group for Riemann elb
    rules:
      - proto: tcp
        from_port: 4567
        to_port: 4567
        group_name: "{{ realm }}_sg_base_server"
        group_desc: security group for all servers
      - proto: tcp
        from_port: 5555
        to_port: 5556
        group_name: "{{ realm }}_sg_base_server"
        group_desc: security group for all servers
    rules_egress:
    ...
```

Comment: Good catch! This is exactly why this website is soooo good. I also think Ansible should warn on such configuration errors...